# get HttpServletRequest in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC. I am not using Spring BOOT.

HttpServletRequest does not work for me, or rather it works, but only in controllers, but it does not work in other classes.

For example, I create an AuthenticationSuccessEventListener class and mark it as @Component which implements the ApplicationListener interface. And in this class AuthenticationSuccessEventListener, HttpServletRequest is not working for me.

I don’t know why it doesn’t work. I have been trying to solve this problem for several days, and I just can't.

When trying to get the HttpServletRequest, I get an exception:

**Message** `No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`

Tell me how to solve this problem?

https://github.com/MyTestPerson/mysite/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mysite/security/listener

**AuthenticationSuccessEventListener**

```
    @Component
    public class AuthenticationSuccessEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {


    //    This option doesn't work.
    //
    //    @Autowired
    //    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    //    And this option doesn't work.
    //
    //    HttpServletRequest curRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
    //                .getRequest();




        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent a) {
            

    //        System.out.println("+=+=+=+=+=+=+: " + httpServletRequest.getHeader());

        }


    }
```

Comment: Which request do you expect to be injected? Why?

Comment: I am expecting to receive HttpServletRequest data

Comment: An `HttpServletRequest` represents an HTTP request. Which specific HTTP request do you expect to have access to on an application event in the listener?

Comment: Authentication on the site. AuthenticationSuccessEvent and AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent

Comment: When I try to login with login and password.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts